# websauna populate table with data from users

Tags: python, model, sqlalchemy, pyramid, websauna

I'm just starting digging into websauna and python frameworks, and have one question.
How can I create a table that will be populating based on websauna.system.user?

For example table 'example' should contain two columns:

1. user_id based on users.id
2. some_float with default value 0.0

And when new user will be added this "example" table will automatically populated with new row "some_user_id_from_users.id | 0.0"

As I understand this populate can be done by `sqlalchemy.backrefs`, but I'm not really clear on how this can be implemented from the documentation because it looks like that "User" class should populate this "example" table.
Or, maybe, I should proceed with modification of user creation process?

Any advise or example will be greatly appreciated

PS sorry for my English)